# Does Calcium Carbonate dissolve in an aqueous solution of sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: aqueous-solution

A countertop company (Wilsonart) advises the use of sodium bicarbonate to remove limescale (solid  calcium carbonate) from the worktop surface. Acidic solutions are contraindicated because the countertop (which is solid laminate, probably phenolic resin) is sensitive to acid. But, does sodium bicarbonate increase the solubility of calcium carbonate, at room temperature? (It does not seem to work)

If not, are there any other ways of increasing the solubility of calcium carbonate without resorting to acid (or other things that would damage a laminate countertop)?

Comment: Sorry carbonate was a typo, fixed now. Meant NaHCO3.

Comment: Calcium carbonate cannot be totally insoluble in any solvant.

Comment: @Maurice hard water is pretty much a good counter-example. You will get more solid calcium carbonate and not less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chemical common sense says that the sodium bicarbonate is not going to make the limescale much more soluble.

On the other hand, the same sodium bicatrbonate is widely used as a mild abrasive (when not fully dissolved in water). This may or may not help in your case (probably not in an aestetically acceptable manner).

On the third hand, whatever your countertop is made of (it is not marble, is it?), it will likely not be vulnerable to the ordinary food-rated acids, e.g. vinegar or lemon juice. This is what you can try with little risk and a great probability of success.

Comment: You might try club soda, seltzer; CO2 dissolves CaCO3 converting it into bicarbonate.

Comment: @jimchmst this is pretty much traditional (this is how calcium carbonate got into the utility water in the first place). On the other hand, for the club soda to work, one would need a lot of time and a lot of soda - and maybe a high pressure setup of some sort. And still falls in "using acid" category.

Comment: Can't upvote yet, but I would if I could @fraxinus